# How can I secure an outwardly opening front door?

Tags: doors

I have just replaced my front door that was inswing with an outswing door per county instructions on new door installation. My question is "how could I secure my door?" My previous door had a chain but I can't use that on my new door. Any clever suggestions?

Comment: I think you may have mis-interpreted the "county instructions".  Residential doors may swing either way. Only exit doors serving an occupancy of 50 or more, shall swing out in the direction of egress. (IBC Section 1008.1.2.)  However, if your door swings out, you might try a "surface bolt."  Try Emtek's website... http://emtek.com/collections-function-view.php?va=y&f=14. Actually, I have a hard time with their website, but they have great service. Give them a call.

Comment: What is the county and state?

Answer (score 1):

### You have three points of attack to deal with

The first, and obvious, point of attack for any door is the lock, and to this end, get something good from a serious locksmith.  Abloy's disc-detainers are the gold standard, but anything from a well regarded brand (note, standard Kwikset locks are [*not*](http://www.frontrangelocksmith.com/blog/schlage-vs-kwikset/) [well-regarded in](http://premiernwlocksmithsalemoregon.com/locksmith-solutions/salem-locksmith-common-locks/) the physical security world, and nor is Master Lock!) with decent pinning (six pins, including security pins and keys that don't look as flat as Kansas) and good anti-drill features (carbide pins or plates) should be secure enough for a residential application.

The second point of attack for an outswing door are the *hinges* -- if you use ordinary hinges on an outswing door, then your hinge pins are wide open to get pulled.  While there are hinges with setscrews or hook-like studs that attempt to prevent an attacker from removing the door by pulling the hinge pins out and then simply pulling the door out, the ultimate solution to this problem is to replace the hinges with *fast-riveted* hinges that simply won't come apart unless you take an angle grinder to them.  This does mean that you won't be able to "take the door off its hinges" to replace it, though -- you'll need to unfasten the hinges from the door or frame in order to replace the door, instead.

The third and final point of attack is the use of a prybar to try to force the door open.  This can be mitigated through the use of a latch plate cover, as well as making sure the strike anchors securely into the frame.

Comment: Can you add citations for the claims that (e.g.) Kwikset is not well regarded? Otherwise the OP has not way to form their own judgement on what may or may not be just your opinion.

Comment: Also need a latch plate cover to prevent attacking the deadbolt itself.

Comment: To Staver's point, I think it'd be great to add the 3rd point of attack (prybar)

Comment: I agree with the points, when we had to enter a property that the tenentants vacated on less than friendly terms I always took a battery drill kwickset usually takes about 15 seconds.+